# angularjs - difficulty replacing "$scope" with "this" and similar

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to slightly reduce the clutter of `$scope` in my angular application, pursuant to several tutorials on the subject. One such article demonstrates a good tactic for cleaning up `$scope` is to instead make my controllers *'classes'*, so to speak. Like this;

```
//Don't do this
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.doStuff = function(){
    //Really long function body
  };
});

//Do this instead
var MyCtrl = function($scope){
  var _this = this;

  _this.doStuff = function(){
    _this.doStuff();
  };
};
```

I am attempting to do this, but am having a great deal of trouble - as it seems that code attached to `_this` is **completely** different than code attached to `$scope`. For instance;

```
var editor = function($scope){
   var _this = this;

   _this.Model = {
      Id: null,
      Editing: false
   };

   _this.options = {
      columns : [
         { field: "Id", width: 25, title: "Identity" },
         { field: "Name", width: 40, title: "Name" }
      ]
   };
};
```

And then attempting to use this in directives ...

```
var gridDirective = function($parse) {
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: true,
      link: function(scope, element, attributes, controller) {
         // I expected this line to output the array I made, but it comes up undefined
         console.log('scope.options: ', scope.options);
      }
   }
};
```

I expected the objects I assigned to `_this` to be available on the `scope` in the directive, but this doesn't happen. It is only when I directly, explicitly assign them to `$scope` do I see them show up in a directive.

Is there any solution to this? Or do I just have to use `$scope` everywhere?

Comment: Why the objects assigned to `this` would be available in the `$scope` variable? `_this` reffers to the function, not to the `$scope`.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but I've found tutorials that have told me otherwise, so I was giving it a try. Check this one out, for example: http://www.technofattie.com/2014/03/21/five-guidelines-for-avoiding-scope-soup-in-angular.html

Comment: The examples are different. I suggest you read again, paying attention to the details. For example, read again the example 1. It says: `$scope.doStuff = function...` and not `_this.doStuff = function...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access these properties in the alias that you have provided in the `ng-controller` ***as*** notation within the scope of the controller's context. So if you're declaring the controller like this:

`ng-controller="EditorController as editor"`

this means that you can access the editor properties within the `$scope.editor` property.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/00z9zf0o/1/)**

*Javscript*

```
.controller('EditorController', function() {

    var _this = this;

   _this.Model = {
      Id: null,
      Editing: false
   };

   _this.options = {
      columns : [
         { field: "Id", width: 25, title: "Identity" },
         { field: "Name", width: 40, title: "Name" }
      ]
   };

})

.directive('grid', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            // I expected this line to output the array 
            // I made, but it comes up undefined
            console.log(scope.editor.options);
        }
    }
});
```

*HTML*

```
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="EditorController as editor">
    <div grid></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Since your directive is already defined with an isolated scope, you better make use of defining the properties and accessing the objects assigned from it, rather than accessing them from the parent scope.

*JAVASCRIPT*

```
.directive('grid', function($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          options: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
            console.log(scope.options);
        }
    }
});
```

*HTML*

```
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="EditorController as editor">
    <div grid="editor.options"></div>
</div>
```

You can learn more about isolate scopes and directives in the **[`$compile` service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile)**.

Comment: So the objective is to minimize the explicit dependency on `$scope` and instead tie it to the `as` notation? I think I see more what the goal is, and what the author was saying, but I'm having a difficult time grasping the advantage this has. Wouldn't it just make the code more coupled?

Comment: The advantage of declaring an alias for the controller is to create a more composed definition of scope when child and grandchild controllers are created. Instead of accessing parent scope via `$scope.$parent` then it would be better to use an alias to access such properties.

Comment: I see. So in that situation, the coupling is actually desired because it reduces some of the other overhead you would incur with the other methods of getting to that data.

Comment: Yes, definitely. As an addendum to your current directive code, it is good practice to make use of an isolate scope's potential, since you're already using it. Don't access the options properties from the parent scope, instead, define them in the directive's scope object notation, so you can access them. I will add an example.

Comment: I'll be honest, I've read over 14 tutorials on isolate scope and it still makes 0 sense to me.

Comment: The reference for creating directives is documented here, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile.

Answer (score 1):

`$scope` needs to be set to `_this` instead of just `this` or `this` to local var at controller level.

A quick sample demo:

```
app.controller('MainController', function(){
  var vm = this;
  vm. error = '';
  vm.onUserComplete = function(response){
    console.log(vm.error);
  };

});
```

John Papa had recommended an approach where you could create Controllers methods using `this`. However, I personally I do see the benefit of deviating from the standard but if you want to read more about this approach here is the article that explains it:

http://www.johnpapa.net/angularjss-controller-as-and-the-vm-variable/

Comment: I am sorry, I am extremely confused as to what you mean. I don't see it clearly in your code example, and I don't see how the article relates to it. I'm pretty lost altogether.

Comment: Are you referring to the section that says "`vm in the javascript`"?

Comment: Hrnm. Well that is basically what I have, I just used the word `_this` instead of `vm`. I don't see how it would yield any different results.

Comment: @Ciel I failed to see your controller declaration like presented on the demo

Answer (score 1):

In your case, if you want achieve using `this` instead of `$scope`, you should do it like this:

```
var editor = function($scope){
   var _this = $scope;

   _this.Model = {
      Id: null,
      Editing: false
   };

   _this.options = {
      columns : [
         { field: "Id", width: 25, title: "Identity" },
         { field: "Name", width: 40, title: "Name" }
      ]
   };
};
```

But this approach doesn't make sense.
The article suggestion is (and in my opinion also)

for controllers use constructor pattern
what does it mean? and what the advantages of that, you will have private which you can not assign to scope and you will have functions which will be assigned to scope by your choose, this will be keep your controller cleaner. Example from this article I think is not right, it should be like this:

```
var MyCtrl = function($scope){
  var _this = this;

  $scope.doStuff = _this.doStuff;
};

MyCtrl.prototype.doStuff = function(){
  //Really long function body, also this bounded with scope
};

MyCtrl.prototype.anotherFunc= function(){
  //This is another function which not bounded to scope
};
```

**UPDATE**

I would like to suggest read this [article](http://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams/?utm_source=ng-newsletter&utm_campaign=4709eb30a4-AngularJS_Newsletter_7_29_147_27_2014&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_fa61364f13-4709eb30a4-96570477)  in this article explained styleguide for angular.

Comment: So you're saying it is better to attach properties to the prototype, and then attach them to the scope? I'm unsure why that would be any better.

Comment: I have updated the example, you can read this article, in that case you are keeping your code cleaner , because if you dont do like this, you must write all you controller stuff in one function.

Comment: I see. So it is more about better modularization than actual code efficiency. That does make more sense.